# PATH wrongly set

Tags: python, django, path

I set up django on my mac and installed it from git into site-packages. I modified my PATH variable as

```
export PATH=~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/django/bin:$PATH`
```

but when I

```
echo $PATH
```

I see that `~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin`

I haven't tested it out to see if it works but was just wondering if this is standard behavior or firstly if it was even recommended to install django in site-packages or install it separately? Either way I thought this behavior was interesting and wanted to share it just incase anyone could provide a good explanation as to what is going on?

Comment: You can simply use a [virtual environment](http://virtualenv.org) and avoid all this.

Comment: Yes that would have been the simpler way to go initially and I have done that but I was curious as to why this was happening and wanted an explanation regarding this peculiar behavior if anyone knew the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is by any chance `~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin` a symlink pointing to `~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/django/bin` ?